# Pyspark drop columns after multicolumn join

Tags: python, join, pyspark

I'm trying to do a left join in pyspark on two columns of which just one is named identical:

How could I drop both columns of the joined dataframe `df2.date` and `df2.accountnr`?

```
dfAll = (
    df1
    .join(df2, 
        [df1.order_date == df2.date, df1.accountnr== df2.accountnr], 
        how = 'left')
)
```

Adding 
`.drop(df2.date, df2.accountnr)` (error: col should be a string) or 
`.drop('date', 'accountnr')` (error: ambiguous column names) does unfortunately not work.

The only solution that I can come up with is first seperately renaming `df2.accountnr` to `df2.accountnr2` and then use `.drop('date', 'accountnr2')`

Is there a better solution to directly drop the joining columns in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the column names directly as part of your join condition, this requires renaming a column on one of the DataFrames (I will choose `df1` for this example). You also no longer have to drop anything afterwards:

```
dfAll = (
    df1
    .withColumnRenamed('order_date', 'date')
    .join(df2, 
        ['date', 'accountnr'], 
        how = 'left')
)
```